# check multiple option same value if one is selected and change the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two or more than loop select option

This is the code:

```
  <select id="select0" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="50">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="300">3</option>
    <option value="100">4</option>
    <option value="200">5</option> -- if this is selected value is 200
    <option value="700">6</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="share0" value=100> --then input is 100

 <select id="select1" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="50">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="300">3</option>
    <option value="100">4</option>
    <option value="200">5</option> ---then this should be change to value is 100
    <option value="700">6</option>
  </select>
   <input type="text" id="share0">
etch...
```

if i select the first select option ex. value=200 is selected
then in the input box i put 100.. the second select should output in the comment tag above

how to do this in javascript or jquery function
your help much appreciated.. tnkyou

Comment: If your task is not symmetrical why do you use the same onChange function?

Comment: Explanation provided isn't really not clear enough and has conflicts in it. In addition you should be providing your own code attempts.

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('share0');
var select = document.getElementById('select0');
function myfunction(){
    input.value=select.value/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the difference of value 200 and 100 from dropdown and input, you can try the following codes:

```
function myfunction()
{
    var select0 = document.getElementById('select0').value;
    var share0 = document.getElementById('share0').value;

    var diff = select0 - share0;
    var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    select1.value = diff;
}
```

The input field should look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="share0" onblur="myfunction();" ></input>
```

Comment: thankyou for the comment charlietfl,avril alejandro and rose000 yeah thats what im trying, to get the difference, but im trying to update all same value on the select.once its the dropdown is seleteced.
what im trying to figure out is when one select is selected
let say select id is select0 i selected value of 50
then put value on share0 to 30 of course the difference is 20
and the 20 should replace or update in other other loop dropdown the new value of 50 is 20.i think need to be array to match the value of selected and to other option in the loop but i dont have and idea..tnkyou so much..